# Background duplicates on burgermenu when adjusting height

Tags: css, reactjs, duplicates

In my burgermenu when I try to adjust the height the background-color duplicates

```
.bm-menu {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    height: 60vh;
    position: fixed;
    transition: top 0.3s;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 30px;
    z-index: 1001;
}


    <div className="bm-menu">
      <Menu isOpen={menuOpen} onStateChange={({ isOpen }) => toggleMenu(isOpen)}>
        <div className="menu-content">
          <a className="menu-item" href="#">Login</a>
          <Link to="/about" className="menu-item">About Us</Link>
          <a className="menu-item" href="#">Membership Plans</a>
          <Link to="/contact" className="menu-item">Contact Us</Link>
        </div>
      </Menu>
    </div>
```

With height: 60vh; it duplicates even tho its the height I want. But its a like a extra layer above that stretches down the full viewport.

Any tips or ideas?

I have tried literally everything and nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `overflow: hidden;` on the .bm-menu class to prevent any content overflow from affecting the background duplication.

Comment: Not working either :(